# How to append an HTML string to a DocumentFragment?

Tags: javascript, html, string, appendchild, createtextnode

I'm adding textnodes to a documentFragment like this:

```
var foo = document.createDocumentFragment();
var someText = "Hello World";
foo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(someText));
```

This works fine, but sometimes I'm being passed "text" which includes inline links like this:

```
var someOtherText = "Hello <a href='www.world.com'>World</a>";
```

Which in my handler is converted to hardcoded text instead of a link.

**Question:**
How do I append an HTML string like the above into a documentFragment? If I'm not using `textNodes` can this be done using `appendChild`?

Comment: You could create a div-tag and use innerHTML.

Comment: can't because it needs to run through my handler which only creates documentFragments

Comment: Let your handler create a div internally, assign the string to innerHTML, and then move the created nodes to the fragment.

Comment: hm. let me try if this works.

Comment: Create div, append div, use outerHTML.

Comment: @CBroe How is outerHTML supposed to help when it returns a string, and you can't append a string to a fragment?

Comment: Does innerHTML only _return_ strings? No. So why are you assuming that was the case for outerHTML …?

Comment: @CBroe  [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) and [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) returns a *string*. A string that could be `<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>Stack overflow</a>` but that is still a *string*. Proof: `var a=document.createElement('div'); a.innerHTML = "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>Stack overflow</a>"; console.log('The types are: %s %s', typeof a.innerHTML, typeof a.outerHTML);`. What are the types? string and string.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, I misunderstood you. Both innerHTML and outerHTML can be used to both SET and GET the value (as a string). However, a documentFragment (that the question is about) can be inserted into another element. Could you show some code where you use outerHTML and where your return a documentFragent?

Comment: I was thinking of pretty much the same as your approach – create a DIV, append that to the fragment, and then replace the div by div.outerHTML="…" (would save appending child elements in the loop) … but that does not seem to work cross-browser, so your approach looks to be more solid.

Answer (score 15):

Create a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement)-element, add the text with `.innerHTML` and get a `documentFragment` with the `content`-property:

```
function stringToFragment(string) {
  const temp = document.createElement('template');
  temp.innerHTML = string;
  return temp.content;
}
```

Now you can create a `documentFragment` from a string, and you can even append a `documentFragment` to a `documentFragment`:

```
const frag = stringToFragment('<div>Hello</div>');
frag.append(stringToFragment('<div>Stackoverflow</div>'));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<span>Hello World!</span>");
```

It returns a DocumentFragment.

Support IE >= 9

**EDIT:**

recent versions **Safari** seems to fail with the short way, here is a little bit longer but working way:

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.body); // Select the body cause there is always one (documentElement fail...)

var fragment = range.createContextualFragment("<span>Hello World!</span>");
```

Comment: Careful! Not standardized.

Answer (score 1):

This may works:

```
var foo = document.createDocumentFragment();
var someText = 'Hello <a href="www.world.com">World</a>';
var item = document.createElement('span');
item.innerHTML = someText
foo.appendChild(item);
document.body.appendChild(foo);
```